# error in ruby on rails app for email contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I followed this [email form](http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/) tutorial for my ruby on rails app which is hosted at heroku. Every time I pull up localhost:3000/contact I get the following error:

No route matches {:action=>"home", :controller=>"contact"}

Here is what is in my routes.rb file:

```
Inspired::Application.routes.draw do
  get "pages/home"
  get "pages/about_us"
  get "pages/web_design"
  get "pages/portfolio"
  get "pages/contact"

  match 'contact' => 'contact#new',    :as => 'contact', :via => :get
  match 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'contact', :via => :post

  root :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

I'm unsure of where I'm going wrong. Why is the action going to home when it is supposed to go to new or create? Thanks!

Comment: Please post your contact/new.html page

Comment: `rake routes` will help to show which routes you have available.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've accidentally named two routes as contact_path (:as names the route) and that's overriding the :get one. If you change the name of the second URL, it should work:

```
match 'contact' => 'contact#new',    :as => 'contact', :via => :get
match 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'make_contact', :via => :post
```

Or maybe changing it to a RESTful resource?

```
resources :contact_messages
```